# Limit to number of Google Maps API keys associated with a given SHA-1 fingerprint (i.e. debug keystore)?

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I have a single debug keystore that I use to sign debug builds for a large number of projects (i.e. package names).

I'm wondering if Google imposes any limits to the number of API keys I can generate with a single debug keystore (and its associated SHA-1 fingerprint).

I don't mind creating new Google Developer Accounts, but I only want to use a single debug keystore across all of them.

Any ideas or experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

For debug keystore I think there is no limit, as we can get API Keys using one Debug key for many applications, however we need one release key for each app for release version of APT keys